# C# OpenXML how to get Hyperlink from Cell

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk

I'm using C# and DocumentFormat.OpenXml to parse an Excel File.
This File has many cells with hyperlinks to external file.

How could I get addresses of those hyperlinks?

I have already tried with this:
https://www.programmersought.com/article/22902085148/
but

```
var hyperlinks = worksheetPart.RootElement.Descendants<Hyperlinks>()
```

raises an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This will do it for you. Change the foreach loop to whatever you want it to do. Right now it writes the URL to console:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filepath, false))
{
    List<HyperlinkRelationship> hyperlinks = spreadsheet
        .GetAllParts()
        .SelectMany(p => p.HyperlinkRelationships)
        .ToList();

    foreach (HyperlinkRelationship hyperlink in hyperlinks)
    {
        string hyperlink_address = hyperlink.Uri.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(hyperlink_address);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The link you provided actually had the correct solution, it wasn't well formatted in my oppinion though. A little tinkering got me the solution.

This is a "quick and dirty" hack thet will get you the hyperlink behind a cell. For easier comprehension i removed all error handling. A few try/catch blocks and null checks might be advisable in there.... ;)

```
public static string GetFullHyperlinkValue(SheetData sd, WorksheetPart wsp, string colIdx, int rowIdx)
    {
        // get all hyperlinks - you might want to store them ...
        var hyperlinks = wsp.RootElement.Descendants<Hyperlinks>().First().Cast<Hyperlink>();

        // get the cell at the address
        Cell cell = sd.Descendants<Row>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.RowIndex != null && p.RowIndex == rowIdx).Descendants<Cell>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.CellReference != null && p.CellReference == $"{colIdx}{rowIdx}");

        // get the Hyperlink object "behind" the cell
        Hyperlink hyperlink = hyperlinks.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Reference.Value == cell.CellReference.Value);

        // if the hyperlink has an anchor, the anchor will be stored without the # in hyperlink.Location
        string location = hyperlink.Location;

        // the URI is stored in the HyperlinkRelationship
        HyperlinkRelationship hyperlinkRelationship = wsp.HyperlinkRelationships.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == hyperlink.Id);
        var url = hyperlinkRelationship.Uri.ToString();

        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(location) ? url.ToString() : $"{url}#{location}";
    }
```